# How do I access the attached volume in Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

I just attached another ebs volume to running instance.  But how do I access the volume?  I can't find the `/dev/sda` directory anywhere.  Where should I look?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you attach an EBS volume, you specify the device to attach it as. Under linux, these devices are `/dev/xvd*` - and are symlinked to `/dev/sd*`

In the AWS console, you can see your EBS volumes, what instances they are attached to, and the device each volume is attached as:

[image: AWS Console]

You can achieve the same thing from the CLI tools.
Set the necessary environment variables:

```
export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/root/pk-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem 
export EC2_CERT=/root/cert-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem
```

Run the command on your current instance (otherwise, just specify the instance-id):

```
ec2-describe-instances `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` | grep BLOCKDEVICE

BLOCKDEVICE     /dev/sda1       vol-xxxxxxxx    2011-11-13T21:09:53.000Z
BLOCKDEVICE     /dev/sdf        vol-xxxxxxxx    2011-11-13T21:09:53.000Z
BLOCKDEVICE     /dev/sdg        vol-xxxxxxxx    2011-11-13T21:09:53.000Z
```

It is worth noting that in both cases above - the CLI and the AWS Console - the devices are described as being attached at `/dev/sd*` - this is not actually the case, however.

Look at the contents of /dev:

```
ls -l /dev/sd* /dev/xv*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       5 Dec 12 18:32 /dev/sda1 -> xvda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4 Dec 12 18:32 /dev/sdf -> xvdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4 Dec 12 18:32 /dev/sdg -> xvdg
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202,  1 Dec 12 18:32 /dev/xvda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 80 Dec 12 18:32 /dev/xvdf
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 96 Dec 12 18:32 /dev/xvdg
```

The devices are actually `/dev/xvd*` - and the `/dev/sd*` paths are symlinks.

Another approach to check for the currently available devices is to use `fdisk -l`, or for a simpler output:

```
cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 202        1    4194304 xvda1
 202       80    6291456 xvdf
 202       96    1048576 xvdg
```

If you need to determine which devices have been mounted use `mount` and `df` - and check `/etc/fstab` to change the mount options.

Comment: Saved my butt. They really need to update those docs.

Comment: FWIW, on recent releases of Xen virtualized Ubuntu instances, the xvd* devices are not symlinked to sd*

Comment: @cbare Can you confirm. When I go into my console I see it a 15 gig volume attached as /dev/sda1. But when I go into my server, the only thing I see is /dev/xvda1. There is no /dev/sd* at all! Also /dev/xvda1 is shown to be 32 gigs with 25 gigs used up. Can I be certain that these 2 are the same volumes?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, Not sure why you'd see different sizes but the xvd_ devices (Xen Virtual Device, I'm guessing) are mapped through the virtualization layer to the equivalently named sd_ device. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166083/what-is-the-dev-xvda1-device

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, This [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html) says, "in most cases, the trailing letter remains the same. In some versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and its variants, such as CentOS), even the trailing letter might also change (where /dev/sda could become /dev/xvde)."

Comment: How come in my server the symlink doesn't exist? Could I create my own symlink to make sure sda1 links to xvda1? The EC2 interface says sda1, but the actual device is xvda1, but with no symlink currently.

Comment: This needs updating. The device you choose when attaching a volume is no longer the device to which the volume is attached.

Answer (score 23):

**To use a EBS volume attached in the EC2, you need first mount the volume.**

1. Connect to your instance using SSH.
2. Use the **lsblk** command to view your available disk devices and their mount points.

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-86-46 ~]$ lsblk`
`NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT`

`xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk`

`└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /`

`xvdb    202:16   0    8G  0 disk`

`xvdf    202:80   0  100G  0 disk`

3. create a file system on the volume, example -> **sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf**
4. create a mount point directoty for the volume ->**sudo mkdir mount_point**
5. To mount this EBS volume at the location you just created -> **sudo mount /dev/xvdf mount_point**
6. To check you can perform **ls mount_point**


   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Comment: This works and it much easier

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Nice and to the point!