# "Device /dev/xvdb not found" AWS EC2 symlinked volume

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have an AWS instance with an encrypted EBS volume, which is at `/dev/sdb`.

I am trying to mount it via ansible using the command:

```
- name: format new volume
  filesystem: fstype=xfs dev=/dev/xvdb

- name: edit fstab and mount the vol
  action: mount=/home/ec2-user/ name= src=/dev/xvdb opts=noatime fstype=xfs state=mounted
```

I have put in `xvdb` after the suggestion from this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/365841/314047

However, I still get the error: `"msg": "Device /dev/xvdb not found."` 
PS: I get this error with `/dev/sdb` too.

This is the O/P of my `ls -l /dev/sd* /dev/xv*`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4 Feb 10 06:45 /dev/sda -> xvda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       5 Feb 10 06:45 /dev/sda1 -> xvda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4 Feb 10 06:45 /dev/sdb -> xvdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202,  0 Feb 10 06:45 /dev/xvda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202,  1 Feb 10 06:45 /dev/xvda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 16 Feb 10 06:45 /dev/xvdb
```

This command: `cat /proc/partitions` gives me this:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

 202        0    8388608 xvda
 202        1    8386543 xvda1
 202       16    8388608 xvdb
```

**Is there anything which I did wrong?  How do I mount my volume and cd into it?**

Comment: Try doing it manually first, then automate it. There are manual steps here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Comment: @Tim Yeah, going through that now :) . Looks like I need to do a lot of steps before I can mount it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you haven't partitioned and formatted it, you will have to first partition it using `fdisk` and then create a ext4/3 partition using `makefs`. You can check out the documentation here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html